# XSLT 1.0 Turn delimited string into nodes

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file which I would like to format but I need a bit of help.

My input is :

```
<X>
    <Y>
        <id>2047866</id>
        <email_address>abc@gmail.com</email_address>
        <senddate>2017-02-02 15:13:27.0941121</senddate>
        <product_id>5000231;5000233;5000237;5000240;5000240;5000241;</product_id>
    </Y>
</X>
```

I need to build an XSL that turns my input into :

```
<X>
    <Y>
        <id>2047866</id>
        <email_address>abc@gmail.com</email_address>
        <senddate>2017-02-02 15:13:27.0941121</senddate>
        <product_id>5000231</product_id>
    </Y>
    <Y>
        <id>2047866</id>
        <email_address>abc@gmail.com</email_address>
        <senddate>2017-02-02 15:13:27.0941121</senddate>
        <product_id>5000233</product_id>
    </Y>
    etc
    .
    .
</X>
```

I found a script that helps me take each ID from product_id but I need to copy also the id,email,senddate above for each product_id and put them into Y parent tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:variable name="delimiter">
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="mark">
    <xsl:variable name="dataList">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:call-template name="processingTemplate">
        <xsl:with-param name="datalist" select="$dataList"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="processingTemplate">
    <xsl:param name="datalist"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($datalist,$delimiter)  ">
            <xsl:element name="processedItem">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($datalist,$delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:call-template name="processingTemplate">
                <xsl:with-param name="datalist" select="substring-after($datalist,$delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($datalist)=1">
            <xsl:element name="processedItem">
                <xsl:value-of select="$datalist"/>

            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>    
</xsl:template>
```

Could you please give me some hints on how to proceed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Y">
    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="product_id"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="';'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="id | email_address | senddate"/>
                <product_id>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
                </product_id>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```